# How to check if a server is up in c?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have 3 programs running.  A client, a main server and a backup server.  I want to somehow determine if the main server is up (did it crash) so that if not I can send the message to the backup.  I have tried if(send(....) >= 0){....}  that obviously didn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: Way to be a smart ass

Comment: The comment is actually correct - just because you haven't specified any relevant data, this is the only solution. What protocol? What request server expects and how it would reply? And once you know all that - question will disappear itself.

Comment: Just let server response certain message, if not response, it's down, can't see what's your problem.

Comment: (I wasn't even trying to be sarcastic. Just a but of fun.)

Comment: you can ping the ip address

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Nope, not plugged in. It uses wireless. :p

Comment: @Megharaj ping will not help to know whether the application was crashed.

Comment: @keltar - Actually, even Ethernet is not a relevant data based on the question.

Comment: Is the server applications's source code under your command? Or do you want simply test if the whole machine is up and running or switched off. Please be more specifiy what you actually want to test.

Answer (score 0):

From your client, you need to continuously try to read data from the server. 
Something like this :
Incase you are using Linux based server/client.

```
while ( (n = read(socket_fd, recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer)-1)) > 0)
{
    recvBuffer[n] = 0;
    if(fputs(recvBuffer, stdout) == EOF)
    {
        printf("\n Error :  error in Fputs\n");
    }
}
```

You can create this socket_fd using connect and passing the server address.